# Strange errors converting video with VLC remotely on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, putty, vlc-media-player, remote

I'm using Putty to connect to my Kali Linux machine remotely. I have an mp4 that I would like to convert to mp3 via command line:

```
cvlc "temp/5b531984164ae64008f644e3236bb09d/" --sout=#transcode{acodec=mp3,vcodec=dummy}:standard{access=file,mux=raw,dst="temp/5b531984164ae64008f644e3236bb09d/input.mp4"} vlc://quit
```

But I'm getting some spectacular errors:

```
VLC media player 2.0.3 Twoflower (revision 2.0.2-93-g77aa89e)
[0xa157d8] inhibit interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[0xa157d8] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x7f154c000b08] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x8980a8] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0x7f154c000b78] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[0x8ced88] mux_dummy mux: Open
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 4.2.0
libdvdread: Encrypted DVD support unavailable.
************************************************
**                                            **
**  No css library available. See             **
**  /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/README.css     **
**  for more information.                     **
**                                            **
************************************************
libdvdread: Couldn't find device name.
libdvdnav:DVDOpenFilePath:findDVDFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO failed
libdvdnav:DVDOpenFilePath:findDVDFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.BUP failed
libdvdread: Can't open file VIDEO_TS.IFO.
libdvdnav: vm: failed to read VIDEO_TS.IFO
[0xa199e8] main playlist: stopping playback
[0xa28ec8] mux_dummy mux: Open
[0xa2a858] main stream error: cannot pre fill buffer
[0xa2d488] idummy demux: command `quit'
```

All the Google-foo in the world isn't helping me decipher this error, and I'm not getting any mp3 output. Any help you can give me is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The first errors are not critical, in fact I am surprised that `cvlc` complains about ...

> inhibit interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11

at all.

What is critical is

> libdvdread: Encrypted DVD support unavailable.

You could have either read `/usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/README.css` or issued the command

```
      apt-cache show libdvdread4
```

to learn that:

> libdvdread probes for libdvdcss at runtime and if found, will use it to
> decrypt sections of the DVD as necessary. libdvdcss needs to be installed from
> third-party repositories (see README.css), it's not included in Debian.

At any rate,

> If it is legal for you to use CSS in your juristiction, you can:
>
> - Manually download and compile the source code from
>   http://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html.

This applies to Debian and all of its derivatives, not just Kali.